# Extract and analyze data from JSON - Hadoop vs Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, data-processing

I'm trying to learn the whole open source big data stack, and I've started with HDFS, Hadoop MapReduce and Spark. I'm more or less limited with MapReduce and Spark (SQL?) for "ETL", HDFS for storage, and no other limitation for other things.

I have a situation like this:

1. **My Data Sources**

   - Data Source 1 (DS1): Lots of data - totaling to around 1TB. I have IDs (let's call them ID1) inside each row - used as a key. Format: 1000s of JSON files.
   - Data Source 2 (DS2): Additional "metadata" for data source 1. I have IDs (let's call them ID2) inside each row - used as a key. Format: Single TXT file
   - Data Source 3 (DS3): Mapping between Data Source 1 and 2. Only pairs of ID1, ID2 in CSV files.
2. **My workspace**

   - I currently have a VM with enough data space, about 128GB of RAM and 16 CPUs to handle my problem (the whole project is a research for, not a production-use-thing). I have CentOS 7 and Cloudera 6.x installed. Currently, I'm using HDFS, MapReduce and Spark.
3. **The task**

   - I need only some attributes (ID and a few strings) from Data Source 1. My guess is that it comes to less than 10% in data size.
   - I need to connect ID1s from DS3 (pairs: ID1, ID2) to IDs in DS1 and ID2s from DS3 (pairs: ID1, ID2) to IDs in DS2.
   - I need to add attributes from DS2 (using "mapping" from the previous bullet) to my extracted attributes from DS1
   - I need to make some "queries", like:

     - Find the most used words by years
     - Find the most common words, used by a certain author
     - Find the most common words, used by a certain author, on a yearly basi
     - etc.
   - I need to visualize data (i.e. wordclouds, histograms, etc.) at the end.

**My questions:**

1. Which tool to use to extract data from JSON files the most efficient way? MapReduce or Spark (SQL?)?
2. I have arrays inside JSON. I know the explode function in Spark can transpose my data. But what is the best way to go here? Is it the best way to 
   extract IDs from DS1 and put exploded data next to them, and write them to new files? Or is it better to combine everything? How to achieve this - Hadoop, Spark?
3. My current idea was to create something like this:

   - Extract attributes needed (except arrays) from DS1 with Spark and write them to CSV files.
   - Extract attributes needed (exploded arrays only + IDs) from DS1 with Spark and write them to CSV files - each exploded attribute to own file(s).
   - This means I have extracted all the data I need, and I can easily connect them with only one ID. I then wanted to make queries for specific questions and run MapReduce jobs.

The question: Is this a good idea? If not, what can I do better? Should I insert data into a database? If yes, which one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need Hadoop rather than importing to a database? If you want better querying and visualizations, Spark won't be able to do everything easily

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for asking!! Being a BigData developer for last 1.5 years and having experience with both MR and Spark, I think I may guide you to the correct direction.

The final goals which you want to achieve can be obtained using both MapReduce and Spark. For visualization purpose you can use Apache Zeppelin, which can run on top of your final data.

Spark jobs are memory expensive jobs, i.e, the whole computation for spark jobs run on memory, i.e, RAM. Only the final result is written to the HDFS. On the other hand, MapReduce uses less amount of memory and used HDFS for writing intermittent stage results, thus making more I/O operations and more time consuming.

You can use Spark's Dataframe feature. You can directly load data to Dataframe from a structured data (it can be plaintext file also) which will help you to get the required data in a tabular format. You can write the Dataframe to a plaintext file, or you can store to a hive table from where you can visualize data. On the other hand, using MapReduce you will have to first store in Hive table, then write hive operations to manipulate data, and store final data to another hive table. Writing native MapReduce jobs can be very hectic so I would suggest to refrain from choosing that option.

At the end, I would suggest to use Spark as processing engine (128GB and 16 cores is enough for spark) to get your final result as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has been of much help. But I still have a question left -  If i have 1:M relationships in my data (i.e. One book was written by multiple authors), what's the best way to store this kind of data? Into rows, like this: row1: (book 1, Author 1), row2: (book1, Author 2)? 
Thank you!

Comment: @user36 if you have largely relational data, a graph or relational database would be better than encoding that into Hadoop flatfiles